# Django - Proper way to separate site-specific content from templates?

Tags: python, django

I have had trouble putting my question into words to Google the answer, but here goes:

Let's say I have **a few strings that appear in multiple places in my Django project**. For example, the site owner's name, contact info, the text on the main page, etc.

Right now they are all **hard-coded into my templates**. Sometimes these need to be changed, and it's especially a pain to replace the strings that appear in multiple places.

What is the proper Django way to **pull this data out of the templates** and into one central location?

Thanks in advance, I want to do this the right way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an app such as [django-chunks](https://github.com/clintecker/django-chunks) which allows you to save small pieces of text in the database and add them to your templates using simple template filters (you reference each piece of text with a slug). So in your template you would have:

```
{% load chunks %}
<html>
  <head>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
        ...
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
        {% chunk "sidebar_disclaimer" %}
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        {% chunk "footer_text" %}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This would create two new entries in the admin interface where you could add and adjust the text that is to appear in the sidebar and footer

There are [plenty of alternatives](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/layout/):

- [django-flatblock](https://github.com/funkybob/django-flatblocks)
- [django-siteblocks](https://github.com/idlesign/django-siteblocks)
- [django-generic-flatblocks](https://github.com/bartTC/django-generic-flatblocks)

Comment: Thank you so much! I will compare them and see which one I like best.